# update method not working in AngularJS with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have encountered a problem in my ruby project. What I am trying to do is just to modify email addresses and update them. However, the emails are just not updated. I also did not get any error messages. I find the debugging process very difficult with angularJS and rails. So, I am desperately looking for help in here.

Personally, I am thinking that the problem might be with the routing or the "name: user" in the factory. 
Please assist me in finding my mistakes. Thank you very much.

This is the manage_users_controller.rb

```
def edit
  if request.format.json?
   t = @user
   @user = {:id => t.id, :email => t.email}
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @user, :status => 200}
    format.html
  end
 end

 def update
  @user.attributes = users_params
  if @user.save
   respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => {:redirect_to => admin_manage_users_path }, :status => 200 }
   end
  else
   respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => {:errMsg => print_out_message('form-update','user'), :error => @user.errors}, :status => 400 } 
   end
  end
 end

 def users_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email)
 end
```

and the edit.html.erb

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="AdminManageUsersCtrl">
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="rs-content" data-ng-init="loadUser()">
   <div class="portlet listing" cg-busy="loadUser" ng-cloak>
     <div class="portlet-body">
      <form name="form" ng-submit="uploadUser()" confirm-on-exit>
       <%= render "admin/manage_users/form" %>
       <div class="row row-space-top-1">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <button type="submit" class="btn red-mint" ng-click="form.$setPristine()">Update</button>
         <%= link_to "Cancel".html_safe, admin_manage_users_path, :class => "btn dark btn-outline" %>
         <%= link_to 'Remove', URI::unescape(admin_manage_user_path(:users => '{{user.id}}')), :method => :delete, :class => "pull-right btn red btn-outline", :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this user?', "ng-click"=>"form.$setPristine()"} %>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and app.js excerpt

```
app.factory('AdminManageUsers', ['railsResourceFactory', 'railsSerializer', function(railsResourceFactory, railsSerializer) {
 return railsResourceFactory({
  url: '/user',
  name: 'user'
 });
}]);


$scope.uploadUser = function() {
  $scope.errors = [];
  AdminManageUsers.$patch('update', $scope.user).then(function(response) {
   $window.location.href = response.redirectTo;
  }, function(response) {
   angular.forEach(response.data.errors, function(errors, key) {
    $scope['form'][key].$invalid = true;
    $scope.errors[key] = errors.join(', ');
   });
   alertMessage.danger(response.data.errMsg, 1, 10000);
  });
 }
```

and the routes.rb

```
resources :manage_users, :only => [:index,:destroy], :param => :id# <== generate new manage_user path
   match "manage_users/data" => "manage_users#data", via: [:post], :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
   match "manage_users/load" => "manage_users#load", via: [:get], :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
   match "manage_users/:id/edit" => "manage_users#edit", via: [:get]
   match "manage_users/:id/update" => "manage_users#update", via: [:patch]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out my mistake. It was because of the device authentication. 
When I update, devise will not allow update of email, so the new email will be stored as unconfirmed email. So I have been looking at the wrong place for solution. It wasn't with the routing etc, but it was with devise :(

To let device allow change of email, I changed the update method in manage_user_controller.rb:

```
 def update
  @user.skip_reconfirmation!
  if @user.update_attributes(users_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => {:redirect_to => admin_manage_users_path }, :status => 200 }
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

your `AdminManageUsers`seem to point to `/user` but your rails resource namespace is `/manage_users`, try to change this in your angular factory and see if this works

Comment: I changed user to manage_users in both url and name in the factory, but update still does not work correctly. :(